# Инструмент для простого создания постеров и инфографики

Tags: изображения, графика

## Каким инструментом рисуются подобные картинки?

Понятно, что художник или дизайнер такое легко сделает в фотошопе/иллюстраторе/etc. Но может есть какое-то средство для простых смертных технарей? Чтобы быстро накидать постер или иллюстрацию, так же легко, как мокап интерфейсов?

[image: картинка1]

[image: картинка2]

Comment: Винда - paint. линукс - gimp. Но без циферблата под углом и без кривых бизье.

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько сервисов, которые могут помочь:

[Infogr.am](https://infogr.am/) — для хорошей инфографики

[Canva](https://www.canva.com/) — поможет вам сделать все, что нужно: обложку, презентацию, подарочный сертификат, фотоколлаж, баннер и т.д.

[Pablo](https://pablo.buffer.com/) — для картинок в социальных сетях. Здесь можно сделать эффектную картинку буквально за пару минут.

[Picovico](https://web.picovico.com/en/home) — для красивого слайд-шоу
Хотите добавить на сайт симпатичный видеоролик, но не знаете, как его сделать? Может, стоит начать со слайд-шоу?

[Quotes Cover](https://quotescover.com/) — для оформления цитат

[BeFunky](https://www.befunky.com/) — для обработки фотографий, вы сможете быстро отредактировать любое изображение — поправить экспозицию, поднять резкость, убрать «шум», наложить фильтр и т.д

[Genially](https://www.genial.ly/) — для создания интерактивного контента